# Gost error after change solution from x32 to x64 win7

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I've changed my VS2010 Solution from x32 Win7 to x64 Win7. All dll's and C:\ path's has changed and the Build => Platform Target is set of "Any CPU". 
Now, sometimes i've got a gost error:

> "the operation could not be completed".

But the Solution has build without errors. 
Sometime i've reboot my computer for starting my VS solution project in debug area and sometime no need for reboot and after little time, see the VS solution works.

Have any body a idea about this Gost error?

kind regards 
Dolce

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of searching I'll propose that you try and disable the VS hosting process ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185330%28v=vs.100%29.aspx ).

Let us know if that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help, but this link below was helpful. Plus I have add the x64 Platform target, there was missing.

[A curious case of Visual Studio 2010 debugger(it can not hit a break point)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5744506/a-curious-case-of-visual-studio-2010-debuggerit-can-not-hit-a-break-point) (I mean the Screenshot).

regards
Dolce