# Upgraded a C# Window Form to VS2010, now Main is not called

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have some legacy code in VS2008 and now I upgraded to VS2010.  The project is targetting x86.  I run it and it immediately terminates.  The main function is not called.  I have set the startup object already.

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main() {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new frmMain());
    }
}
```

Here is what the project look like:

[image]

EDIT:  There is absolutely no output in the Output window.  And I know it's immediate termination because I can click on the Run button again right after I clicked on it already!

Here is what the Solution Property look like:

[image]

Comment: Does it throw an Exception somewhere?

Comment: Nope.  Nothing at all.

Comment: Nothing on output window? how many projects in that solution ? how do you know it immediately terminates if you dont see anything

Comment: Absolutely nothing in the Output window.  I know it's immediate termination because I can click on the Run button immediately!  EDIT:  I added a screenshot of the project setup.

Comment: you run with debug and a break point in the Main() ? Have you tried to run it with the VS2008 again ?

Comment: I have definitely tried to add a break point of course, the break point does not hit.

Comment: Did you check your build options in the project properties and see what the startup object is set to? Try setting it to either Program.cs or frmMain.cs.

Comment: It's set to Program.cs, check screenshot.

Comment: Your screenshot of the `Program` class is not showing a namespace, like it is showing in your Project Options (Startup object `ImportItems.Program`). Could there be another `Program` class floating around?

Comment: Could this be related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5744506/a-curious-case-of-visual-studio-2010-debuggerit-can-not-hit-a-break-point

Comment: Have you tried running the .exe directly (not through VS) and then either attaching a debugger on  load to see what's executed or just seeing if it crashes?

Comment: Got it!  Just needed a good cleaning :p  VS was holding up the file, so clean wasn't doing it's job.  I had to shut everything down in Task Manager, manually delete the bin folder, then rebuild!  But it works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it! Just needed a good cleaning :p VS was holding up the file, so clean wasn't doing it's job. I had to shut everything down in Task Manager, manually delete the bin folder, then rebuild! But it works now.