# WCF C# webservice returns nothing, ends client unexpectedly

Tags: c#, wcf, service, web

I have several web services residing on a LIVE server that return data to a client. For some reason since I have moved the services from TEST server to the LIVE server the services are breaking.

My logs indicate that the services are executing correctly serverside but on the client side 'nothing' is returned. I.e. the client exists unexpectedly and the local variables defined 'do not exist in the correct context' when debugging.

```
PDFLive.PDFServiceClient client = new PDFLive.PDFServiceClient();

string[] response = client2.ReceiptPDF("document string");
string foo = "othercodetobeexecuted";
```

If I debug over this code, it will attempt to execute 'string[] response ...' and then just skip over the other code and end the client without returning any errors or exceptions and making the local variables

```
string[] response
```

and

```
string foo
```

'Non existent in the current context'

I have enabled Diagnostics in my web.config and they indicate no errors. Again on the serverside the code executes correctly its the return data that isnt reaching the client or reaching the client but not being processed correctly on the client side.

Ive tried creating the default WCF project and deploying it on my LIVE server and consuming it externally alas, same issue. Could it be something on the Server that is disallowing data to be sent?

I have searched high and low but without any meaningful error being returned its difficult to know what the issue could be. Has anyone had any experience with this issue or come across it in anyway?

I can consume the service via an external test client but when adding a service reference to a C# project it displays the behaviour mentioned above.

SOLVED:
 I had to uncheck 'optimize' code in the project settings and my debugger works perfectly now. I got the idea from this post [A curious case of Visual Studio 2010 debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5744506/a-curious-case-of-visual-studio-2010-debuggerit-can-not-hit-a-break-point)

Comment: Has your service code changed at all? What about the data contract types?

Comment: Thanks Hugh, I solved the problem! I had to uncheck 'optimize' code in the project settings and my debugger works perfectly now.

Comment: Cool - please add as an answer and mark it as your solution to help others who had the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED: I had to uncheck 'optimize' code in the project settings and my debugger works perfectly now. I got the idea from this post [A curious case of Visual Studio 2010 debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5744506/a-curious-case-of-visual-studio-2010-debuggerit-can-not-hit-a-break-point)